# Redirect Google AMP URLs to its canonical url using htaccess - but exclude images

Tags: redirect

I used this redirect with a reg ex to remove the /amp at the end of the url:

```
# Remove AMP
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/amp(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
```

But this redirects these images, too:

/media/amp.jpg

How do I exclude images like png, jpg, webp from the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
# Remove AMP
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|jpe?g|webp)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/amp(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
```